# Can I open MS Files in Document Library using Web Browser?

Tags: document, library, word

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I want to open a Word file in my web browser not on my MS Office installed on my Computer. I tried opening Excel file on my web browser and it worked, but I can't open a Word file on my web browser. Is there a way that I can do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Spideynok and welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange.

The simple answer to your question, is that you can indeed access documents without having the Microsoft Office Suite installed using "Office Web Apps". Please see the TechNet link below, which will guide you in setting up and viewing some videos on the functionality.

Per [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855124.aspx),

> When used with SharePoint 2013 on-premises, Office Web Apps provides
>   updated versions of Word Web App, Excel Web App, PowerPoint Web App,
>   and OneNote Web App. Users can view and optionally edit Office
>   documents by using a supported web browser on computers and on
>   different mobile devices, such as Windows Phones, iPhones, and iPads.
>   In addition to new features in Office Web Apps, the architecture and
>   deployment methods have also changed, which allow Office Web Apps to
>   provide viewing functionality for Exchange Server 2013 and Lync Server
>   2013.